# How to uninstall DBeaver?

Tags: 14.04

I download Dbeaver from the site, the Enterprise Edition 
and installed it using

```
sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-ee_5.0.1_amd64.deb
```

now I have tried uninstalling/removing it using the bellow commands

```
sudo dpkg -r dbeaver-ee_5.0.1_amd64
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove dbeaver
```

as suggested in some sites,but I get error messages as

> warning: ignoring request to remove dbeaver-ee_5.0.1_amd64 which
>   isn't installed

and

> Package 'dbeaver' is not installed, so not removed

the dbeaver exists in

/usr/bin/dbeaver
/usr/bin/X11/dbeaver
/usr/share/dbeaver

Answer (score 22):

I had `dbeaver-ce_xxx`, and I tried both of:

```bash
sudo dpkg --purge dbeaver
```

```bash
sudo dpkg --purge dbeaver-ce_xxx
```

Both got the same result. It was not removed.

However, if (also per Aditya's suggestion) I tried just:

```bash
sudo dpkg --purge dbeaver-ce
```

Then it was removed.

Granted, I had to remove some folders under `/usr/share/dbeaver`, but that was only because I had put some files there that were not in the original installation.

Just a data point. Maybe it will help with `dbeaver-ee`.

Answer (score 6):

I had to uninstall it with `snap` using the following command

```
snap remove dbeaver-ce
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use below commands

```
dpkg --purge package_name
```

`--purge` will remove all configuration files.

**Updated** :
You can remove the package file in director /var/lib/dpkg/info/ and update source.

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/[package_name].*
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get update
```

Then, reinstall your package:

You can read [this](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/#document-ch-maintainerscripts).

Comment: I have even done that

Comment: did you check rebooting system, that package still there in /usr/bin?

Comment: yes, its still there

Answer (score 2):

I did it with running command:

```
sudo dpkg -r dbeaver-ce
```

Note: I have run this from the same directory where i have run

```
sudo dpkg -i dbeaver-ce_6.2.3_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

None of these completely worked for me.
I needed to delete configuration files (workspaces) that should be removed with an uninstall but are not.

Yes, to remove DBeaver and all associated configuration files:

```sh
sudo apt purge dbeaver-ce
```

OR (I found it no difference in using dpkg):

```
sudo dpkg --purge dbeaver-ce
```

**THEN**

Purges are useless against these files, so you have to remove them yourself.

```
rm -rf ~/.local/share/DBeaverData
```

Also note that you'll want to remove any workspace files in your $HOME directory:

```
rm -rf ~/*workspace6
```

DBeaver devel team decided to something awesome and brilliant, which was to store prefs in the `~/.eclipse` directory. So you'll need to delete that too.

```
rm -rf ~/.eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

We can remove Dbeaver at any time we want from our Ubuntu Linux if the software is creating any problem or is not useful anymore to you. Here are the commands to do that:

For APT users:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge dbeaver-ce
```

For SNAP users:

```
sudo snap remove dbeaver-ce
```

For Debian Binary:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge dbeaver-ce
```